# typescript callback function without parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to write some callback functions without parameters.

can anyone tell me below code is correct in typescript or javascript?

```
myfunction(completeCallBack, failCallBack) {
     if (some_condition) {
         completeCallBack;
     }else {
         failCallBack;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
function myfunction(completeCallBack, failCallBack) {
     if (some_condition) {
         completeCallBack();
     } else {
         failCallBack();
     }
}
```

What you were missing is: `()`.
If you don't include that then the function won't be executed.

For example:

```
function fn(): number {
    return 10;
}

let a = fn; // typeof a is () => number
let b = fn(); // typeof b is number
```

---

#### Edit

If your function expects two functions with no args then it shouldn't be passed functions who expects args.
You can use typescript to check for that:

```
type NoParamsCallback = () => void;

function myfunction(completeCallBack: NoParamsCallback, failCallBack: NoParamsCallback) {
     if (some_condition) {
         completeCallBack();
     } else {
         failCallBack();
     }
}
```

Then, if you have a function with args but you'd like to pass it anyhow, then you can use the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function:

```
function logNumber(num: number): void {
    console.log(`this is the number: ${ num }`);
}

myfunction(logNumber.bind(10), () => {});
```

Comment: but wait, the function completeCallBack or failCallBack are the functions are passed outside. Then who knows they have parameters or not?

Comment: Check my revised answer.

Comment: your example is not concerned with my case.

Comment: What is your case? You asked a pretty general question and so I wrote a general answer. If you have a specific case then edit your question and explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is a superset of javascript. So if it's correct in javascript it sure is correct in typescript;

1. `myfunction` is not defined as a function. It's not valid in javascript. It would be valid in typescript if it would pe part of a class.
2. your code does nothing except evaluating `some_condition`. It should either call the callbacks or return them.

This is how I think it would be correct:

```
function myfunction(completeCallBack, failCallBack) {
     if (some_condition) {
         completeCallBack();
     }else {
         failCallBack();
     }
}
```